# Падает MySQL сервер после последовательных 10-15 запросов на сайт

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, vps

При обращении 15 раз подряд и больше (через F5) сервис mysql нужно включать заново. В err логах из важного:

```
170404 19:15:06 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
170404 19:15:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170404 19:15:06 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170404 19:15:06 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170404 19:15:06 [ERROR] Aborting
```

И иногда еще такая ошибка:

```
170404 19:15:00 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1047280 bytes)
```

Но при ней mysql не падает, просто ошибка на сайте.

Сервер - VPS 1гб ОЗУ. Сайт на WordPress.
На главной стр (которую тестил) в MySQL ~250 запросов (что для WP чуть ли не норма)

Начал пытаться вникнуть в конфигурирование mysql. И вроде бы даже всё понятно по отдельности. Получилось добиться ускорения раз в 10 (до этого вообще не работал сайт толком, постоянно падал). Но я не так силён в администрировании, видимо, либо не замечаю чего-то. Нужен опытный совет. Вот текущий конфиг:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 0

wait_timeout = 60000
max_allowed_packet  = 160M
key_buffer = 64M
read_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 32M

thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 16
thread_concurrency  = 6

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
table_cache = 512
max_connections = 20

query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1

log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err
log_warnings = 1

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 160M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 64M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: В логе у вас ошибка попытки выделить память под buffer pool InnoDB (памяти не хватает), а в конфиге `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M`. Не думали, что эти два факта как-то связаны? На вашем одногигабайтном сервере живёт же не один только MySQL, но и вебсервер и PHP. Всем им нужна память, возможно её надо расходовать более экономно.

Comment: Я пробовал 128 и 256. И проблема осталась. Я думал, что выделение памяти происходит на момент старта сервиса mysql. Разве это не так?

Comment: Судя по ошибке память выделяется в момент регистрации подсистемы хранения InnoDB. Но возможно дело не в базе данных. Попробуйте локализовать проблему: сколько памяти свободно до старта mysql, сколько после, сколько памяти использует php при обращении к странице, которую вы обновляете 15 раз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот абсолютно рабочая конфигурация для 2ГБ сервера. Сайты на WordPress. Ничего не падает.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

max_connections = 64
key_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 2M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 64M

init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

sql_mode = "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Как Вы думаете, что может ключевым в Вашем конфиге? Ведь они достаточно похожи...

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2, query_cache_size, max_heap_table_size

Comment: Много читал разного. Раньше было почти как у вас. Тоже были проблемы. Оказалось, что 3 параметра выше - критичны. с max_heap_table_size вообще лажа по умолчанию. Да, почти все параметры пропорциональны памяти, делите на 2, кроме тех, что меньше или равны 128М

Comment: А почему дублируются конфиги? innodb_buffer_pool_size innodb_log_file_size query_cache_size. Работать будет тот, что дальше от начала документа?

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение. Но вот не могу понять, как к этому я мог бы прийти сам. Подскажете может, что читануть? Я не админ, но мне интересно администрирование и конфигурирование.

Comment: Не подскажу, к сожалению. читал очень много статей в Инете, просто поиском выходил на них.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56554/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).